# Customizing social features in 2013

Tags: custom, 2013, best-practices, social

I'm looking at making use of the social features in 2013 but would like to tailor the UX / behaviour in some cases.

I noticed that Microsoft advise against customization - http://www.cmswire.com/cms/information-management/microsoft-doesnt-advise-you-customize-sharepoint-2013-016608.php.

With this in mind, does anyone have a view of best practices in this area? Where would a newbie start (quite happy to get my hands dirty with code)?

Comment: 2013 is as yet an untamed animal. But the basics of it are that it is all based around apps and the search servers. Depending on your level of experience, depends on where to go first. How experienced are you in 2010? 2007? and Office development?

Comment: I've written some webparts and other bits and pieces but my experience is largely based around general web technologies and development rather than SharePoint specifically.

I'm quite keen to understand how I can get the kind of user experience and behaviour I want from the social features whilst using as much of what Microsoft provide out of the box as possible.

Comment: Okay well you want to google this phrase "Developing SharePoint Online Windows Azure Apps" This search will give you everything from how to host to basic apps to create. This is the basic 2013 model, and where you should focus yourself first.